# Pycharm (JetBrains) cannot modify the read-only directory on my macbook

Tags: python, django, macos, pycharm

I am using Mac OS High Sierra and trying to learn Django framework over Pycharm IDE. But my directories are only read only and so I cannot add more files or make changes on the existing files. I tried in Pycharm > File > Make Directory Writeable but it did not help either. This question has been answered for Windows or Ubuntu but those commands do not work at least on my Mac. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand why your directories are read-only. Who does that? How? And why not stop doing that? If it's clear that you have to write something into them.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Go to you **folder**

   cd Desktop/myfolder
3. Run this command

   sudo chmod 777 -R *

Answer (score 2):

Change permission of your project by `chmod` command, open terminal and go to your project then run this command:

```
sudo chmod 775 -R *
```

it changes your project permission and you can read and write on their files.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) .